# "Conventional" vs. "traditional"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *conventional* and *traditional*?

E.g.:

> My grandfather used to live a conventional/traditional life.

Comment: Did you compare dictionary definitions? Why do you think you might confuse the two?

Answer (score 6):

**Conventional**: refers to what is generally expected by people  based on what is common, at a specific time, in a specific culture.

**Traditional**: refers to customs and usages that have been handed down  from past generations to present  time.

For example, if you were getting married, a "traditional" wedding dress based on someone's culture might red, but in the U.S., a "conventional" dress is floor-length and white.

Also, families can have traditions. In a conventional Thankgiving dinner in the U.S., you have turkey, cranberry sause, stuffing, mashed potatoes.

Your grandfather may have lived both a traditional and a conventional life!!

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, **traditional** means "adhering to customs that are respected because they are time-honored or integral to a certain culture or history". **Conventional** is closer to meaning "adhering to old or accepted customs".

The difference lies in that **conventional** can have different meanings based on context, and some of them are negative, lending **conventional** more of a negative shade than **traditional**.

Conventional can also mean "non-progressive", "boring", "conformist", "unimaginative", depending on where it is used. For example, **conventional methods** is neutral, just meaning "usual methods", but **conventional thinking** is more negative, meaning "unimaginative/non-progressive thinking".

In the example sentence you provided, the more likely correct word would be **traditional**, as in that context it means "living according to time-honored ways".